# Tensorflow custom layer: `slice index X of dimension 0 out of bounds`. What does it mean?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, layer, tensorflow-autograph

I am playing around with Tensorflow+Keras and I'm trying to build a custom layer that feeds preprocessed data into the rest of the model. The input is an array of floating point values representing a time series and I want to compute on-the-fly deltas, ratios and mean values of slices.

For example, if the input is `[1, 1.5, 3.2, 4]` the output should be:

```py
[
  1, 1.5, 3.2, 4,   # the inputs get copied
  0.5, 1.7, 0.8,    # deltas: d[i] - d[i-1]
  1.5, 2.13, 1.25,  # ratios: d[i] / d[i-1]
  1.25, 1.9, 2.425  # means:  d[0:i] / i
]
```

For `n` inputs there will be:

- `n-1` deltas
- `n-1` ratios
- `n-2` means

Therefore, if the input size is `n`, the output size must be `4*n - 4`.

I managed to create a working example by forcing eager execution when compiling my model with `model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)` and here it is.

```py
import time
from typing import Final

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


class Enricher(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, input_dim: int, **kwargs):
        super(Enricher, self).__init__(name="enricher", **kwargs)

        if input_dim < 2:
            raise ValueError("input_dim < 2 not allowed")

        self.input_dim = input_dim

    def _mymean(self, ll: list[float]) -> float:
        return float(sum(ll) / len(ll))

    def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
        dtype = self._compute_dtype

        result = [[] for _ in range(inputs.shape[0])]

        # iterating over the first dimension which is the batch size
        for row_idx in range(inputs.shape[0]):
            result[row_idx] = [
                inputs[row_idx][i] for i in range(inputs.shape[1])
            ]  # copying the inputs

            # appending the deltas
            result[row_idx].extend(
                [
                    inputs[row_idx][i] - inputs[row_idx][i - 1]
                    for i in range(1, self.input_dim)
                ]
            )

            # appending the ratios
            result[row_idx].extend(
                [
                    inputs[row_idx][i] / inputs[row_idx][i - 1]
                    for i in range(1, self.input_dim)
                ]
            )

            # appending the "last k values" means
            result[row_idx].extend(
                [self._mymean(inputs[row_idx][-i:]) for i in range(2, self.input_dim)]
            )

        return tf.stack(result)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        # n inputs
        # n-1 deltas
        # n-1 ratios
        # n-2 means
        # n + (n-1) + (n-1) + (n-2) = 4*n - 4
        return 4 * input_shape - 4
```

Unfortunately, eager execution is really slow, so slow that a batch of 32x101 gets preprocessed in roughly 20 seconds. So I tried converting the `call` method into a `tf.function` like so (and I also removed the `run_eagerly=True` from the model compilatio):

```py
def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor) -> tf.Tensor:
    dtype = self._compute_dtype

    print(inputs.shape)

    # result = [[] for _ in range(inputs.shape[0])]
    result = tf.TensorArray(dtype, size=4 * self.input_dim - 4)

    idx: int = int(0)
    
    for i in range(self.input_dim):
        result = result.write(idx, inputs[i])
        idx += 1

    # appending the deltas
    for i in range(1, self.input_dim):
        result = result.write(idx, tf.math.subtract(inputs[i], inputs[i - 1]))
        idx += 1

    # appending the ratios
    for i in range(1, self.input_dim):
        result = result.write(idx, tf.math.divide(inputs[i], inputs[i - 1]))
        idx += 1

    # appending the "last k values" means
    for i in range(2, self.input_dim):
        result = result.write(idx, tf.math.reduce_mean(inputs[-i:], axis=1))
        idx += 1

    return result.stack()
```

But I always end up with this error:

```
File "/.../training/layers.py", line 68, in call
      for i in range(self.input_dim):
    File "/.../training/layers.py", line 70, in call
      result = result.write(idx, inputs[i])
Node: 'model_0/enricher/strided_slice_100'
slice index 100 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
     [[{{node model_0/enricher/strided_slice_100}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_11030]
```